# Sticky property hides overflowing items (React + Material UI)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Good evening, I am doing a user event interface in which I want to scroll down and keep the header (events) sticky on top. Problem is when I add the sticky property, event names are being covered by their right sibling.
This is with sticky:

[image]

And this without it (diagonal names are shown as expected, but of course, header doesn't stick on top on scroll)

[image]

JSX:

```
  <TableRow>
    <TableCell className={styles.blank}></TableCell>
    {props.permissions.map((permission) => (
      <TableCell key={permission.id} className={styles.header}>
        <div className={styles.headerInner}>
          <span className={styles.headerInnerSpan}>{eventType.name}</span>
        </div>
      </TableCell>
    ))}:
  <TableRow>
```

JS-CSS:

```
  blank: {
    position: 'sticky',
    top: '0',
    zIndex: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  header: {
    position: 'sticky',
    top: '0',
    background: 'white',
    zIndex: 20,
    padding: 0,
    height: '140px',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    borderBottom: '1px solid #ccc',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
    overflow: 'visible',
  },
  headerInner: {
    transform: 'translate(17px,45px) rotate(310deg)',
    width: '30px',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  headerInnerSpan: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    overflow: 'visible',
  },
```

I tried moving properties up to TableRow but had same results.

**EDIT**
I created a Codepen for easier debugging. Issue is I can't set the header and blank classes to sticky.
https://codepen.io/Alhwin/pen/YzxMmjx

Main issues to fix:

1. Items overlaps so I can't read diagonal names on Header bar.
2. Header bar and blank div should sticky on top when scrolling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try removing `width` from `.headerInner`?

Comment: @morganney width actually helps me keep the inner div inside its parent. Otherwise they start growing weird outside

Comment: I would set up a codepen or easier way for others to help you debug.

Comment: @morganney fantastic idea. I am updating the main post right now :) thanks